# How can I install the latest Haskell Platform on debian?

Tags: linux, haskell, debian, development-environment

I want to install the latest Haskell Platform on my Raspberry Pi.

Unfortunately my linux-fu is very weak. I can `apt-get install haskell-platform` which works, as far as it goes, but installs a very old version from the official package repository. Part of the code I want to compile only compiles against GHC 7.8.

Comment: You can install the generic linux binary from here for Debian: http://www.haskell.org/platform/linux.html#binary

Comment: The [debian package repo](https://packages.debian.org/search?keywords=haskell-platform) does not list the 2014 Haskell Platform yet, but you can always use the [generic linux binary](http://www.haskell.org/platform/linux.html) and install it with the instructions on that page.  Alternatively, you can try installing it from source, which I find to be fun and educational.

Comment: I don't think he can use the generic binary on a rasberry Pi, and I don't know of any arm-capable distro that ships with 7.8. I think this is very much a non-trivial endeavor.

Comment: At the moment GHC-7.8 is available from Debian "experimental" suite: https://packages.qa.debian.org/g/ghc.html

Answer (score 1):

You can get the latest GHC Debian Packages from http://deb.haskell.org

Instructions for installation [here](https://github.com/bitemyapp/learnhaskell#debian)

Answer (score 1):

As the comments discuss, the `experimental` suite contains [(very) recent ghcs](https://packages.qa.debian.org/g/ghc.html) (including ghc release candidates).

You can install packages from there like so:

```
apt-get update
apt-get -t experimental install packagename
```

`unstable` [also contains](https://packages.debian.org/source/unstable/ghc) ghcs that are actually released.

And the [generic linux binary platform](https://www.haskell.org/platform/linux.html#linux-generic) also will work with debian.